# How to find text inside word file that has different background?

Tags: c#, delphi

I need to search inside Word file and find all the text that has different background colors (highlighted) and write only the founded text into new word file. how I can do that ?

I tried using this code:

```
uses ActiveX, ComObj;
const
  wdFindContinue = 1;
  wdLine=5;
  wdStory = 6;
  wdExtend = 1;
  wdCharacter = 1;
var
  OleObj: Variant;
begin
  // create OLE object for MS Word application:
  OleObj := CreateOLEObject('Word.Application');
  // load a document from your file
  OleObj.Documents.Open(YourDocument);
  OleObj.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting;
  OleObj.Selection.Find.Text := strFinna;
  // WordApp.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text := yourNewStringForReplace;
  OleObj.Selection.Find.Forward := True;
  OleObj.Selection.Find.MatchAllWordForms := False;
  OleObj.Selection.Find.MatchCase := False;
  OleObj.Selection.Find.MatchWildcards := False;
  OleObj.Selection.Find.MatchSoundsLike := False;
  OleObj.Selection.Find.MatchWholeWord := False;
  OleObj.Selection.Find.MatchFuzzy := False;
  OleObj.Selection.Find.Wrap := wdFindContinue;
  OleObj.Selection.Find.Format := False;
  OleObj.Selection.HomeKey(unit := wdStory);
  while OleObj.Selection.Find.Execute do
  begin
    OleObj.Selection.EndKey(Unit := wdLine, Extend := wdExtend);
    OleObj.Selection.MoveRight(Unit := wdCharacter, Count := 1);
    OleObj.Selection.MoveUp(Unit := wdLine, Count := 1, Extend := wdExtend);
    OleObj.Selection.Delete(Unit := wdCharacter, Count := 1);
  end;
  OleObj.ActiveDocument.Save;
  OleObj.Quit;
  OleObj := Unassigned;
end;
```

Is there any documentation for all office OLE Object methods ?

Comment: The code you are provided does not appear to do anything like what you are requesting.

Comment: yes I provide it here only as a reference

Comment: @Dsm I already know that and I did not find a way to do what I want. Helping should not be only to fix code but maybe a link for documentation or something can help me do what I want.

Comment: Looking at the code you supplied, hopefully you understand it at least to some extent. Based on that you should be able to write some basic code that at least opens two documents and sets your selection either to hunted for text (if that is what you want) or isolates a word (if that is what you want). As it stands you just look like you are throwing some random code it to avoid a downvote, but have actually done nothing, in the hope that someone will do your work for you. That certainly puts me off trying to help.

Comment: Of course the Office's interfaces have extensive documentation. Did you try installing it?

Comment: @FreeConsulting was looking for a link for documentation do you know ?

Answer (score 1):

The code below shows how to scan a Word document character-by-character and reports the background color of the character:

```
procedure TForm1.DoCheckBackground;
var
  OleObj: Variant;
  YourDocument : String;
  Moved : Integer;
  Range : OleVariant;
  Color : TColor;
begin

  YourDocument := 'D:\aaad7\officeauto\parabackground.docx';
  // create OLE object for MS Word application:
  OleObj := CreateOLEObject('Word.Application');
  OleObj.Visible := True;
  // load a document from your file
  OleObj.Documents.Open(YourDocument);
  repeat
    Moved := OleObj.Selection.MoveRight(Unit := wdCharacter, Count := 1);
    if Moved > 0 then begin
      Range := OleObj.Selection.Range;
      Color := Range.HighlightColorIndex; 
      Memo1.Lines.Add(OleObj.Selection.Text + ':' + IntToStr(Color));
    end;
  until Moved <= 0;
```

I tested this with a document containing a middle paragraph which has a turquoise background, the rest being white.  The code correctly reports the HighlightColorIndex as 3 for the middle para and 0 for the rest.

For reference, see e.g.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.highlightcolorindex.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.moveright.aspx

Comment: Appreciate your help. please explain this line `Moved := OleObj.Selection.MoveRight(Unit := wdCharacter, Count := 1);` and what is `unit` ?

Comment: If you took a look at the Word typelib import unit (e.g Word2000.Pas), you could answer these points for yourself.  MoveRight was in your own code, and moves the selection point rightwards in the document by `Count` units.  `wdCharacter` is one of the various units of measurement (others include `wdWord`, `wdLine` etc - just look in the import unit.  I didn't bother to look up the documentation, I just recorded a Word macro that changed the text's background color and looked it its source.

Comment: Well I dont understand code in imported tyelib this is why I asked for explanation or a documentation, anyway thanks

Comment: I've added a couple of document references to my answer.  If you want to do any serious work manipulating Word documents via automation, the place to start learning/reading are its `Selection` and `Range` objects.

Comment: @Wel:  What prompted you to un-accept my answer, as a matter of interest?